# How to click ionic button with PhantomJS and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, phantomjs, webdriverwait

We have a third party vendor that needs to provide us with real-time data but doesn't have any data interfaces. The solution is to mirror the web site data to our system. Their website is built with Ionic.

I have already created the functionality to mirror the data my issue at the moment is that the live data is on a different page but the URL does not change only the source of the page. I am unable to get the live data currently as I have to click on the Live Data button on the home page.

I have used PhantomJS to try and click on the button programmatically but for some reason, it does not want to work. Tested the functionality with Google home page and works correctly.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong or missing? I have tried className, tagName and most of the elements in the dom but still no luck.

Here is the source of the website and my PhantomJS code.

PS The website is a local device interface and I am using saved HTML code to test with.

Web site Button Source

```
<button class="item item-block item-md" ion-item="" menuclose=""><ion-icon color="primary" item-left="" role="img" class="icon icon-md icon-md-primary ion-md-home item-icon" aria-label="home"></ion-icon><div class="item-inner"><div class="input-wrapper"><!----><ion-label class="label label-md">

                Home
            </ion-label></div><!----></div><div class="button-effect"></div></button><button class="item item-block item-md" ion-item="" menuclose=""><ion-icon color="primary" item-left="" role="img" class="icon icon-md icon-md-primary ion-md-list item-icon" aria-label="list"></ion-icon><div class="item-inner"><div class="input-wrapper"><!----><ion-label class="label label-md">

                Live Data
            </ion-label></div><!----></div><div class="button-effect"></div></button><button class="item item-block item-md" ion-item="" menuclose=""><ion-icon color="primary" item-left="" role="img" class="icon icon-md icon-md-primary ion-md-analytics item-icon" aria-label="analytics"></ion-icon><div class="item-inner"><div class="input-wrapper">
```

C# PhantomJS Code:

```
_driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1000, 800);
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
//get the source of the page
Console.Write(_driver.PageSource);
//fully navigate the dom
var pathElements = _driver.FindElementsByTagName("button");
pathElements[1].Click();
```

Comment: You are 100% sure that the button you want to click is the **second** button on the page? Is there a more specific selector you could use to be even more sure? Is the button in the HTML, or is it loading after the initial HTML load through JS?

Comment: Please update your question to show the HTML as retrieved from `View Source`.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the desired element with text as **Live Data** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following solution:

- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='item item-block item-md']//ion-label[@class='label label-md' and normalize-space()='Live Data']"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this solution but no luck but I think its because the Button is in the side bar menu and its not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the generic PhantomJSDriver and the specific browser driver.

Using the ChromeDriver and opening the website in the browser it's working now. I am able to click the button programmatically and go to the correct source.

Also, the button I was trying to press was in the side menu and was not visible. Used one of the elements in the center and that made it work.

I sure you can do this without having the browser open but for now, this will work for the functionality to work.